# Quick way to send file from one branch to another

Tags: git

Is there a quick way to inject a file (version) into another branch from the current branch?

Currently, I copy the file to a non-git location from branchX, than switch to branchY, and copy it there from the non-git location I saved it.  But that looks like too many manual steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [cherry-pick](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) the commit that added the file in branchX to branchY:

```
git checkout branchY
git cherry-pick <sha1>
```

If you made other changes in the same commit they will also be copied over to the current branch.

Comment: excellent.  i never used `cherry-pick` but know have an idea what it is for.  THANKS

Answer (score 1):

To only copy the file (with no other changes or commit history):

```
git checkout branchY
git checkout branchX -- /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 1):

Cherry-picking a whole commit is often the right way to get "the file that goes with the commit" (since often you also need any changes made to other files in the same commit).

A direct answer to your question, though, is that you can view, or even check-out, a specific file within a specific commit:

```
git show <commit-ID>:<path>        # see the file
git checkout <commit-ID> -- <path> # bring it here
```

The `<commit-ID>` part can be anything that resolves to a commit SHA-1 (or even a tree SHA-1), such as a branch name like `branchX`, a relative history version ("what did this file look like three commits ago?  ah, I know how to see: `git show HEAD~3:path/to/file.txt`), or of course a raw SHA-1.

The difference between `show` and `checkout` is that `show` just looks at the contents (prints it to the standard output), while this form of `checkout`, with the `-- <path>` argument, writes the file through the index (so it will be committed on next check-in) and then into your working directory.

There are some subtleties with "smudge filters" as well (`show` skips them and `checkout` uses them), but unless you're using smudge filters, that probably won't affect you.

Note that a `<path>` is generally taken from the top of the repository; if you are in a sub-directory, you can `git show HEAD~3:./file.txt` to avoid having to remember/type-in the exact path to the sub-directory.